# Найти объект в массиве

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Я новичок, мне нужна ваша помощь, есть такой код:

```
var data =[
        {
            "id": "0001",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Cake",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters":
                {
                    "batter":
                        [
                            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                            { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                            { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                        ]
                },
            "topping":
                [
                    { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                    { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                    { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                    { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                    { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                    { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0002",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Raised",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters":
                {
                    "batter":
                        [
                            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
                        ]
                },
            "topping":
                [
                    { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                    { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                    { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                    { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0003",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Old Fashioned",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters":
                {
                    "batter":
                        [
                            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                        ]
                },
            "topping":
                [
                    { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                    { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                    { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                ]
        }
    ]


    var donutSearch = "Chocolate";

    var donutId = data.filter(function(val) {
      return val.id === donutSearch;
    })[0].id;
```

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в консоль вывелись все значения с "type": "Chocolate". 
Мой код выше выдает ошибку "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined"
Еще я пробовал вот так:

```
let searchTerm = "Chocolate";
let battersId = data.find(donut => donut.type === searchTerm).id
```

Та же самая ошибка, что и выше

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие-нибудь решения

Comment: После фильтрации нужно значение не найдено, то есть пустой массив. А вы пытаетесь к нему обращаться по [0]

Comment: У вас в нескольких местах "type": "Chocolate". Для какого надо?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko хотя бы до первого

Comment: _"type": "Chocolate"_ - на третьем уровне вложенности, а проверяется только первый, у которого тип только `donut`, поэтому ничего и не находится

Comment: @Grundy  дело говорит. Я то же самое хотел сказать, но не получилось)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так можно если структура всегда такая как Вы написали:

```
let search = "Chocolate";
data.forEach(d => {
  filterAndLog(d.batters.batter);
  filterAndLog(d.topping);
});

function filterAndLog(arr){
  arr.filter(b => b.type === search).forEach(c => console.log(c))
}
```

```js
var data =[
        {
            "id": "0001",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Cake",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters":
                {
                    "batter":
                        [
                            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                            { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                            { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                        ]
                },
            "topping":
                [
                    { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                    { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                    { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                    { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                    { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                    { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0002",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Raised",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters":
                {
                    "batter":
                        [
                            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
                        ]
                },
            "topping":
                [
                    { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                    { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                    { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                    { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                ]
        },
        {
            "id": "0003",
            "type": "donut",
            "name": "Old Fashioned",
            "ppu": 0.55,
            "batters":
                {
                    "batter":
                        [
                            { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                            { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                        ]
                },
            "topping":
                [
                    { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                    { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                    { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                ]
        }
    ]

let search = "Chocolate";
data.forEach(d => {
  filterAndLog(d.batters.batter);
  filterAndLog(d.topping);
});

function filterAndLog(arr){
  arr.filter(b => b.type === search).forEach(c => console.log(c))
}
```

Вот вариант с глубоким поиском, без расчета на циклические ссылки..

```
let search = "Chocolate";
traverse(data)

function traverse(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    let value = obj[key];
    typeof value === "object" &&  traverse(value);
    key === "type" && value === search && console.log(obj);
  });
}
```

```js
var data =[
            {
                "id": "0001",
                "type": "donut",
                "name": "Cake",
                "ppu": 0.55,
                "batters":
                    {
                        "batter":
                            [
                                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                                { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                                { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                            ]
                    },
                "topping":
                    [
                        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                        { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                        { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
                        { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
                        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                    ]
            },
            {
                "id": "0002",
                "type": "donut",
                "name": "Raised",
                "ppu": 0.55,
                "batters":
                    {
                        "batter":
                            [
                                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" }
                            ]
                    },
                "topping":
                    [
                        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                        { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
                        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                    ]
            },
            {
                "id": "0003",
                "type": "donut",
                "name": "Old Fashioned",
                "ppu": 0.55,
                "batters":
                    {
                        "batter":
                            [
                                { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                                { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" }
                            ]
                    },
                "topping":
                    [
                        { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
                        { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
                        { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
                        { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
                    ]
            }
        ]

let search = "Chocolate";
traverse(data)

function traverse(obj) {
  Object.keys(obj).map(key => {
    let value = obj[key];
    typeof value === "object" &&  traverse(value);
    key === "type" && value === search && console.log(obj);
  });
}
```

Comment: больше forEach богу forEach :)

Comment: @Grundy ну да, мог еще map написать =)

Comment: @Stranger in the Q а что значит filterandLog?

Comment: @Alexandr эм, не понял вопрос, это функция, которую я создал..

Comment: @Stranger in the Q в которую переданы свойства, я правильно понял?

Comment: @Alexandr да, те свойства, которые массив и потенциально могут содержать то что Вы ищете, посмотрите вторую реализацию, она посложнее, но проезжает весь объект в глубину

Comment: @Stranger in the Q а если реализовать с помощью .find, то получится тоже самое что и с помощью .filter?

Comment: @Alexandr нет, find вернет первый найденный обьект, а filter массив всех найденных

Comment: @StrangerintheQ объясни, пожалуйста, что значит эта строчка и что в ней значит "b" и "c" arr.filter(b => b.type === search).forEach(c => console.log(c))

Comment: пока считайте что b => console.log(b) это короткая запись function(b){console.log(b)}

Comment: b и c это произвольные имена аргументов функций, я мог  выбрать любые